# How read All the IOT HUB devices C2D messages in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub

In azure IOT Hub, I have multiple IoT Edge devices and I want to read all the cloud to device messages in python. I am unable to find the way how to read all the devices messages from cloud to device. I have tried paho.mqtt and azure.iot.device.aio, it works perfect for the one device.

Please suggest how to achieve this in Azure using Python.

Answer (score 1):

IoT Hub Message Routing enables users to route device-to-cloud messages to service-facing endpoints. As Message routing enables users to route different data types namely, device telemetry messages, device lifecycle events, and device twin change events to various endpoints.

By default, messages are routed to the built-in service-facing endpoint **(messages/events)** that is compatible with [Event Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/services/event-hubs/).

With the Azure IoT Hub [Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-toolkit) Visual Studio Code, you could easily read device-to-cloud messages from the [built-in endpoint](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-iot-toolkit/wiki/Monitor-IoT-Hub-D2C-Message). If you are using Visual Studio, you could also use [Cloud Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.CloudExplorerForVS) to [monitor device-to-cloud messages.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-visual-studio-cloud-device-messaging)

Refer to the [blog](https://anthonychu.ca/post/end-to-end-realtime-python-iot-azure-functions-signalr-iothub/) to see how we can get messages from Azure IoT Hub from all the devices.

Sample code as below, this can be set in a loop to get all the device messages by getting all the device list first.

```
import os
import asyncio
from six.moves import input
import threading
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubDeviceClient
 
 
async def main():
    conn_str = "HostName=***.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=MyRPi;SharedAccessKey=***"
    # The client object is used to interact with your Azure IoT hub.
    device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(conn_str)
 
    # connect the client.
    await device_client.connect()
 
    # define behavior for receiving a message
    async def message_listener(device_client):
        while True:
            message = await device_client.receive_message()  # blocking call
            print("the data in the message received was ")
            print(message.data)
            print("custom properties are")
            print(message.custom_properties)
 
    # define behavior for halting the application
    def stdin_listener():
        while True:
            selection = input("Press Q to quit\n")
            if selection == "Q" or selection == "q":
                print("Quitting...")
                break
 
    # Schedule task for message listener
    asyncio.create_task(message_listener(device_client))
 
    # Run the stdin listener in the event loop
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    user_finished = loop.run_in_executor(None, stdin_listener)
 
    # Wait for user to indicate they are done listening for messages
    await user_finished
 
    # Finally, disconnect
    await device_client.disconnect()
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
 
    # If using Python 3.6 or below, use the following code instead of asyncio.run(main()):
    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(main())
    # loop.close()
```

More information about C2D [messages](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53677.python-azure-iot-sdk-how-to-send-and-receive-c2d-messages.aspx#Receive_cloud-to-device_messages_in_local_app)

Comment: Hi @SaiKarri-MT, the links you have provided is for telemetry to Azure IoT Hub(i.e. D2C message)  and I am looking for Device to cloud messages. The Sample code you mentioned above will work only for one device and I want to read the messages of multiple devices available in the IoT hub.

Comment: I understood your requirement, mentioned code will help us to get the messages and we can get the list of device ids and can make the entire code in a loop to pass device id's.